# Whats best, one large SQL Database, multiple smaller ones, or multiple smaller tables?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm about to rebuild an online service that uses a single SQL Server 2016 database to manage a few hundred clubs with around 40k members. Its running nice and fast at the moment. However the system could quadruple in clubs and members very soon. That would mean a members Table of 16k members and other tables with many more records than members (ie attendance records etc). 
Would it be more efficient to create a single database for each club (thats potentially around 1200 databases) or to keep one database for all? Or would creating separate tables for each club be more efficent? (Data interaction between the clubs isn't necessary)

Comment: 16k rows is trivial to say the least. SQL Server can easy handle millions of rows in a single table. If this is running nice and fast currently why are trying to redesign it in the first place? That sounds like premature optimization which is the practice of using non-standard design patterns to fix a performance problem that doesn't exist. It is also pure evil. Sounds to me like you should just leave it alone and address the situation when you actually have a performance problem. But...separate tables for each club sounds truly horrific.

Comment: I prefer a single database with well designed indexes and queries.  Indexes are there to make sure a larger database does not seize up.  Also I dislike the practice of making similar tables for different groups (clubs etc) - why not have one table with 'ClubID'  - much better than tabClub1, tabClub2,.....

Comment: This is a faq. Eg google your title.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably some DBAs who have strong opinions on this (I am not a DBA), but I personally would not want to manage 1200 or more databases. Depending on the size of the rows in the Members table, you could easily fit millions or billions of records in it. Size shouldn't be a concern in that regard. As long as the database is properly normalized it makes sense to me to keep it as one database. There are all kinds of factors that should be considered when making a decision like this. How efficient would it be to manage backup/restore or disaster recovery for 1200 databases? How efficient would it be to actually create 1200 databases? How easy would it be to have to manage 1200 disparate databases that are all exactly (or almost exactly) the same as far as schema, the only difference being the data in them?

Comment: I've got strong opinions on it!  People go down the multiple database route for the wrong reasons.  My comany did it due to fear of companies seeing other companies data due to bugs.  Fear of large database sizes that were actually small enough to fit in mobile phones.  Wanting to be able to retrieve databases for debugging (would have been simple to create a means of extracting an anonomizing data).  Wanting to be able to customise, but then started a program of making all the customised DB's identical.

Answer (score 0):

Having 1200 databases would be a nightmare to administrate.

If data for clubs are similar, you can have only one table for all clubs.

In order to separate the data you can create 1200 views to show only individual clubs.

Also, for other reporting purposes it would be handy to have Stored Procedures. One per report with group name as a parameter. For example:

```
EXEC sp_Club_Attendance @ClubName = 'ABC Heroes';
EXEC sp_Club_Annual_Budget @ClubName = 'XYZ Pilots';
```